# Read PE and find SAFESEH status in C++ (make use of RVA)

Tags: winapi, portable-executable

- I'm using imagehlp.h to parse my binary and get LOADED_IMAGE.
- -`LoadedImage.FileHeader->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_LOAD_CONFIG].VirtualAddress`

The above gets me the RVA for IMAGE_LOAD_CONFIG_DIRECTORY
As I unsderstand, RVA are offsets to my desired data structure.
So, `(PIMAGE_LOAD_CONFIG_DIRECTORY)(RVA+LoadedImage.MappedAddress)`

should return me my structure correctly (?). 
Is this the right way to convert RVA to meaningful pointer.
I am not sure because the timestamp value in

PIMAGE_LOAD_CONFIG_DIRECTORY->TimeDateStamp does not show correctly.

On examination of the memory,
My LoadedImage.MappedAddress points me to "MZ" header. Which is the start of the binary file. Which means my baseaddress is correct. So I conclude that I'm not correctly using the RVA.

Anyone knows the correct way to use the RVA?

Before anyone points out, I've check that the value of virtualaddress for  OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_LOAD_CONFIG].VirtualAddress` is not 0 before proceeding further.

Comment: RVA is short for *Relative Virtual Address*. To get the *absolute* virtual address, add the RVA to the base address of the module. The base address of a module is identical to the `HMODULE` returned from a call to, for example, `LoadLibraryEx`.

Comment: @IInspectable, I'm using MapAndLoad() from Imagehlp.h. This returns me with LOADED_IMAGE structure. One of its members is "MappedAddress". This MappedAddress when examined in Memory leads me to the "MZ" header which is the start of the PE file in my memory. Is adding my RVA to this wrong?